# QueryDisplayConfig() does not initialize pathArray and modeArray correctly

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to set-up an easy 1-click change of the mode of my screens (extended <--> disconnected)
but my screens are assigned no ID by the `QueryDisplayConfig` method.

(I'm using the User32 PInvoke lib from https://github.com/AArnott/pinvoke, in addition to what you can find in the code below)

I tried:

- stepping through the code with breakpoints, making sure EVERY value is the default value.
- elevating VS to run with administrator privileges.
- making extra sure that the flags and errors are functioning correctly.

```cs
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(uint flags, ref uint numPathArrayElements, ref uint numModeInfoArrayElements);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int QueryDisplayConfig(
    uint flags,
    ref uint numPathArrayElements, DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[] pathArray,
    ref uint numModeInfoArrayElements, DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[] modeInfoArray,
    DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID[] currentTopologyId
);

const int QDC_ALL_PATHS = 1;
const int QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS = 2;
const int QDC_DATABASE_CURRENT = 4;

public static void CheckDisplays() {
    uint numPathArrayElements = 0;
    uint numModeInfoArrayElements = 0;
    uint filter = QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS;

    int bufferError = GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(filter, ref numPathArrayElements, ref numModeInfoArrayElements);

    DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[] pathArray = new DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[numPathArrayElements];
    DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[] modeArray = new DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[numModeInfoArrayElements];

    int queryError = QueryDisplayConfig(filter, ref numPathArrayElements, pathArray, ref numModeInfoArrayElements, modeArray, null);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Elements: " + numPathArrayElements); // Prints the correct amount of connected screens.
    Console.WriteLine("BUFFER ERROR: " + bufferError);      // Prints 0 -- as in Success.
    Console.WriteLine("PATH ERROR: " + queryError);         // Prints 0 -- as in Success.

    for (int i = 0; i < pathArray.Length; i++) {
        if (pathArray[i].sourceInfo.id != 0) { Console.WriteLine($"Path{i} has been initialized correctly!!"); }
        // Every object in the array has default values and IDs of 0.
        // Nothing prints here.
    }
}
```

Each screen should be assigned an ID and a proper mode.

Instead, everything has the default value and I seem to be stuck.

Comment: Should probably make clear that the main reason I'm doing this is to be able to [change between the Multiple Displays settings](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/312132327348240384/600603941419483158/unknown.png) found on [the Display settings](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/312132327348240384/600598252131188756/unknown.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your declaration for **QueryDisplayConfig** is wrong : arrays must be **[Out]**

This works for me :

(I have only 1 monitor but the values received in arrays are the same as in C++ (I translated structures from SDK headers))

(*IntPtr.Zero* for *currentTopologyId* with *QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS*)

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int QueryDisplayConfig(uint flags, ref uint numPathArrayElements, [Out] DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[] pathArray,
        ref uint modeInfoArrayElements, [Out] DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[] modeInfoArray, IntPtr currentTopologyId);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works flawlessly!

I found it from [the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig), but how was I supposed to recognize that they were supposed to be marked with `out` ?

Comment: When a parameter receives a value , it is normally _out_ or _ref_ (ref is usually used for a In/Out variable, which can be initialized and which  can change when the function returns, like _numPathArrayElements_)